# Send Ctrl-Space via TeamViewer

Tags: macos, emacs, teamviewer, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using TeamViewer from OSX to Ubuntu 16.04. My emacs on Ubuntu doesn't respond to `C-SPC`. Has anyone else encountered and fixed this problem?

`C-SPC` and all other keys work locally on the remote machine.

Comment: Does Ctrl-Space work locally on the Ubuntu machine?

Comment: Tried Cmd/Space? [Though you might have to persuade Spotlight to not intercept it first.]

Comment: I'd think that Command would be interpreted as Hyper, but as not a Mac person what would I know.

Comment: Does Ctrl+Space work in other applications?

Comment: @Gilles: good question. It appears to be no. I tried emacs in an xterm. I just ran `xev`, the event listener, and it sees the press of Control, but doesn't get the `C-SPC` press but it does get `C-x` and others.

Comment: @Tetsujin: I'd have to figure out how to disable Spotlight which I could do, but that's probably not the solution. Besides, other `C-` combinations are passed through as-is.

Comment: Ctrl-space is caputured by the system input method.